# How to override default Apache camel mechanism of putting an Endpoint into Registry?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel, endpoints

How do we override the default Apache camel mechanism of putting an **Endpoint to a Registry** ?
My **Endpoint is a Queue**, and Camel makes Registry entry for a **Queue with the KEY** as the **Queue- Name**.
I want to change that **key to my Custom name**, so that **two Queues** hosted on different Machines but having **same names**, can be put into Registry with different key Entries..

*Can anyone please help ?*

Comment: Are you using a custom component? You can override the getEndpointKey method in your endpoint class and return whatever you want as the key to be used.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.  I am not creating a custom Endpoint. I have a JmsQueueEndpoint object.  Even if I create a custom Endpoint I will not be able to cast a JmsQueueEndpoint object to the custom endpoint.   How do I proceed then ? TIA.